# React Native - How to store captured images inside the app instead of storing in gallery and uploading them to AWS s3 from the app itself

Tags: react-native

I am beginner in react native. I am developing an app where I take photos using react-native-image-picker and upload those to AWS server. I can capture and I am able to upload to AWS s3 Currently , those images are storing in the gallery. But I want to store them inside my app only (It should not store in the gallery) and then uploading to AWS s3. How can I do this. 
Then, I can upload taken photos to AWS s3 when there is net connection only. Therefore, I want to store inside the app and once net connection is back those should get uploaded to AWS s3.(Like what's app). How can I achieve this. (I did not uploaded styling code here)

My code is,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Platform, StyleSheet,Alert, Text,TouchableOpacity,     
    View,Picker,Animated,Easing,Image} from 'react-native';
    import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
    import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3';

     export default class SecondScreen extends Component<Props> {
            constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              file :'',
              //declare array to store all taken images 
              saveImages : []
            }

          }
      takePic(){
        ImagePicker.launchCamera({},(responce)=>{
          const file ={
            uri : responce.uri,
            name :responce.fileName,,
            method: 'POST',
            path : responce.path,
            type :  responce.type,
            notification: {
                enabled: true
              }
          }
            this.state.saveImages.push(file);

        })
      }

   _upload=(saveImages)=>{
        const config ={
            keyPrefix :'uploads/',
            bucket : 's3merahkee',
            region :'us-east-2',
            accessKey:'***',
            secretKey :'***',
            successActionStatus :201
          }

          this.state.saveImages.map((image) => {
               RNS3.put(image,config)
              .then((responce) => {
                console.log(saveImages);
              });
          });
      }
        render() {

          return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.Camera}>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePic.bind(this)}>
                        <Text>Take Picture</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.Send}>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._upload()}>
                        <Text>Send</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
            </View>
          );
      }
    }
```

Comment: what error r u getting ?

Comment: @Hardik Virani . Thank you for the quick response. Here, I  am not getting any error. I need to store the captured images inside my app only. Those should not be store in gallery. From my app only I need upload those pictures to s3.

Comment: This code is working fine in case of uploading once after capturing using react-native-image-picker

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the `storageOptions.cameraRoll: false`

```
  takePic(){
    ImagePicker.launchCamera({storageOptions.cameraRoll: false},(responce)=>{
      const file ={
        uri : responce.uri,
        name :responce.fileName,,
        method: 'POST',
        path : responce.path,
        type :  responce.type,
        notification: {
            enabled: true
          }
      }
        this.state.saveImages.push(file);

    })
  }
```

Take a look at the [API reference](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#options) for more options.

As for a temporary storage, you can use react-native's [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) to store local app data. You'll have to convert the image to a base64 string first as AsyncStorage can only store strings.

Comment: Currently, I am using like this, const options = {
          quality: 1.0,
          maxWidth: 50,
          maxHeight: 50,
      }

    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options,(responce)=>{}

Comment: If I did not store anywhere, How can I upload those photos to aws s3 once net connection is back

Comment: Edited my answer!